# How to assert function wrapped in debounce is called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component that renders an input. When the input is changed, a debounced version of the change handler passed through props is called.

I'm trying to assert that the change handler is called, but according to Jest it isn't.

WrappedInput

```
    import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

    const WrappedInput = ({ data, onChange }) => {

        const [value, setValue] = useState(data.value);

        const handleSave = useCallback(
            value =>
                debounce(() => {
                    onChange({
                        value,
                    });
                }, 500),
            [onChange]
        );

        const handleChange = useCallback(
            event => {
                setValue(event.target.value);
                handleSave(event.target.value);
            },
            [saveChange]
        );

        return (
            <div data-testid="input-container">
                <Input
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    };
```

WrappedInput.test

```
test('save occurs', async () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn(() => {});

    const { getByTestId } = renderWrappedInput({ data: {}, onChange });

    const input = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('input-container').querySelector('input'));
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'asdf' } });

    expect(onChange).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

I get the error `Expected number of calls: 1 \n Received number of calls: 0`. I've also tried mocking `lodash.debouce` by adding `jest.mock('lodash.debounce', () => () => onChange());` below the `onChange` declaration and get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to either remove the debounce when testing, or use fake timers so you don't need to wait for the actual debounce time. Jest's own fake timers don't seem to work with Lodash' debounce. I've found that [`@sinonjs/fake-timers`](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers) works. You'll want to install the fake timer before the tests and uninstall it afterwards. This will replace `setTimeout`, `Date`, etc. with fakes that you control.

```
import FakeTimers from '@sinonjs/fake-timers'

let clock
beforeEach(() => {
  clock = FakeTimers.install()
})
afterEach(() => {
  clock.uninstall()
})

test('save occurs', async () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn(() => {});

    const { getByTestId } = renderWrappedInput({ data: {}, onChange });

    const input = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('input-container').querySelector('input'));

    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'asdf' } });
    clock.tick(500) // advance the clock by the amount of the debounce

    expect(onChange).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

If your React component needs to do something async i.e. needs to wait for a promise to resolve, use `await clock.tickAsync()` instead of `clock.tick()`. The ***Async variants of the fake timer break the event loop and let promises execute.

As a side-note, you might want to use `@testing-library/user-event` instead of `fireEvent` - it exposes a higher level API for clicking, typing, hovering, and so on. It simulates real typing more accurately - it for example clicks on the control first and has optional delay between keystrokes.

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

// ..
// fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'asdf' } });
// ↓
userEvent.type(input, 'asdf')
```

Comment: right, jest for a long time was [unable to handle lodash's debounce](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3465) since it relies not just on timers but also checks time. It should be possible for jest starting from version 26, but imo your solution is more reliable than upgrading jest

Comment: Good to know! Thank you for the addition. Looks like that feature also just uses `@sinonjs/fake-timers` under the hood! https://jestjs.io/docs/en/next/jest-object#jestusefaketimersimplementation-modern--legacy

Comment: Unfortunately, this still didn't fix the issue for me, using Jest 24.7. I ended up going with your suggestion of disabling debouncing for tests, which I don't love but it's good enough. Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: @PartyPanda One thing you could try is check if `await clock.tickAsync(500)` makes a difference. Another thing you could try is make your own `debounce` util which just wraps lodash' debounce, but lets you set the debounce time to 0 in tests. Then you could try `await clock.nextAsync()`. The latter is what I've used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.debounce` with `{ leading: true }` option. This will cause the callback to be called once immediately, allowing the test to pass. See the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce).

```
const handleSave = useCallback(
  value => debounce(
    () => onChange({ value }), 
    500, 
    { 
      leading: true,
      trailing: false,
    }
  ),
  [onChange]
);
```